# Import API in apim

Tags: api, azure-api-management, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an API app hosted in a private / internal ASE.
This is to avoid access to the Api directly from internet.

I have provisioned an Apim that is available public Aly. 
I would like to import the Api's in private Ase into the. Apim.

Any recommendations / reference will be of great help.

Thanks
Sendhil

Comment: The Apim is configured to use internal VIP.There is a application gateway configured to allow access to the internet / public.

Answer (score 2):

If you API has a Swagger / OpenAPI spec doc, you could [simply import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-api-from-oas) that as is.
Worst case, you could always [define your APIs manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually).

Note that you would have to make sure your APIM instance can access your API hosted in ASE (same VNET or [VNET peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal) if required) and would have to set the backend URLs with the API's internal IP.